# The MySQL57 service on Local Computer started and then stopped

Tags: mysql, sql-server, windows

When I try to start my SQL server, a message pops up saying that it starts but then stops. This happened after a restart on my server.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Most of the time this is a permissions issue: Look for the mysql error log: That will tell you what is really happening.

Comment: The error log file will be located under the directory : "%PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\". That might be the best solution which gives you some clues to resolve the problem.

Comment: I only see files with names like `ib_logfile0_2017-12-07T17-16-29`, but they are binary

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the data directory has full permissions set for users "Network Service" and Administrator and that you have quotes around the name of the directory if there are spaces in it.  Make sure that basedir is set / not commented out.

I tested these things by changing the data directory, which re-caused the error you describe above exactly, then fixed the permissions of the newly created data directory to eliminate the error.  I can switch back and forth now my changing which data directory I comment out.  (only as a test, otherwise that's kind of nuts).

C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini Should be something like this, using Windows 2012 R2 server to test:

```
# Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to 
this.
basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/"

# Path to the database root
# datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Data"
datadir="d:/ProgramData/Data"
```

Comment: where is this 'mysqld'? does not available in version 8

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps:

1. run 'cmd' as administrator,
2. cd to your SQL folder,
3. run 'mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --console' to reset and
4. run 'net start mysql' to start the service.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me except for uninstalling the current 5.7.35 and then installing the 5.7.31. Try downgrading. Might help!

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow please get tour here https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read help center for give best feedback

Answer (score -1):

add to config file my.inf  on C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir=C:/temp
```

and everything will work fine .