# MySQL57 service on Local Computer started and then stopped

Tags: mysql, windows

I'm having a problem with mySql. It is stopped and when I try to start it, I get the following: "MySQL57 service on Local Computer started and then stopped." as you can see in the following image:
[image]
My server log is the following:

2017-04-05T10:04:58.085384Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use -`-explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-04-05T10:04:58.085384Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2017-04-05T10:04:58.087363Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.9-log) starting as process 7852 ...
2017-04-05T10:04:58.108397Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-04-05T10:04:58.109398Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-04-05T10:04:58.109398Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-04-05T10:04:58.110399Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-04-05T10:04:58.110399Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2017-04-05T10:04:58.116403Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-04-05T10:04:58.116403Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-04-05T10:04:58.156434Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 8M, instances = 1, chunk size = 8M
2017-04-05T10:04:58.158435Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-04-05T10:04:58.200443Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-04-05T10:04:58.207479Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 43061044961
2017-04-05T10:04:58.208477Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 43061045173
2017-04-05T10:04:58.209476Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Ignoring the redo log due to missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT between the checkpoint 43061044961 and the end 43061045173.
2017-04-05T10:04:58.210477Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2017-04-05T10:04:58.514809Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-04-05T10:04:58.515786Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-04-05T10:04:58.515786Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-04-05T10:04:58.516785Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-04-05T10:04:58.517786Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-04-05T10:04:58.517786Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-04-05T10:04:58.519788Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

I have tried, some options like [turn off innodb_log_checksums via command line or set innodb_log_checksums = 0 in configure file. and then restart](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85307), or [this one in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910680/the-mysql57-service-on-local-computer-started-and-then-stopped) but It is still stopped. 
What can I do? Can some one help me?

Thank you

Comment: in a situation like this, it could well be a port conflict. Check which port it is trying to start on, then see if that one is in use. Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670755/the-mysql-service-on-local-computer-started-and-then-stopped

Answer (score 4):

Run the command from the command prompt; it's the *only* effective way to see the error message that services return that you will *not* see using the built-in Windows Services program.

1. Either double-click the service or right-click to click on *Properties*.
2. Click on the *Path to executable*.
3. Press the Home key and then hold Shift while pressing the End key to highlight the entire command.
4. Hold the Control key and then press C to copy.
5. Run the command prompt (usually Start -> Run -> cmd -> Okay) or make a new shortcut and just type `cmd` for the command.
6. In the commend prompt right-click.
7. Left-click on paste.
8. Press Enter to run the command.
9. Research the problem with your preferred search engine, use "quote operators" around the error message to limit results if there are too many unrelated results.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem, way i solved it was:

- In the command prompt go to mysql location `mysql\bin` (use `cd ..` to go back one folder or `cd name_of_folder` to access it)
- In this location, type `mysqld --initialize`

Answer (score 0):

here what I did and it worked. MySQL keep backup of your my.ini files in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` directory in windows, rename a recent backup of *.ini to my.ini

Answer (score 0):

good thing for me as i have two computers with mysql installed on it. i just copied the my.ini file on the other computer. pasted it on the broken mysql pc. then everything got fixed after that. magic ^_^