# setup mysql lower version with existence of higher

Tags: mysql

If I have on my windows machine installed with mysql installer, for example mysql server version 8.0.21 how can I install in addition server version 8.0.13?

Comment: Install WAMPServer, in that you can switch easily between multiple versions of MySQL. You can also switch between multiple version of Apache, mariaDB, PHP

Comment: Do you want to run both versions at the same time or just start one version then stop that and start the other

Comment: I want to run specific 8.0.13 version on pc that have already installed newer version of mysql. I need only mysql. I try to setup as described here - http://mysqlbugs.blogspot.com/2014/08/basic-windows-mysql-installation.html but got an error that service started and stopped , try - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670755/the-mysql-service-on-local-computer-started-and-then-stopped , but without results.

Answer (score 0):

solved:

Mysql server files I put into "C:/mysql"

1. my.ini file in mysql folder:

> [client] port=4306
>
> [mysql] default-character-set=utf8
>
> [mysqld] port=4306 max_allowed_packet=16M
>
> basedir="C:/mysql/" datadir="C:/mysql/data/"
>
> default-storage-engine=INNODB max_connections=1000 tmp_table_size=128M
> thread_cache_size=256 myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
> myisam_sort_buffer_size=256M
>
> key_buffer_size=512M read_buffer_size=64K read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
>
> sort_buffer_size=2M
>
> innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1 innodb_log_buffer_size=6M
> innodb_buffer_pool_size=550M innodb_log_file_size=110M

2. Open cmd as ***administrator*** and go to bin folder with command

> cd C:/mysql/bin

.
3. cmd run :

> mysqld.exe --install mysql_8013 --local-service

(mysql_8013 - service name, I used as id for my version)
install takes parameters from my.ini file
4. cmd run :

> mysqld --initialize --console

--console command will output result and we can see steps or errors.

**!And here we have an important data : root temporary password**
Looks like this:

> [Note] [MY-010454] [Server] A temporary password is generated for
> root@localhost: ake8_ig8CGpe

5. cmd run :

> sc start mysql_8013

or from windows services - start our mysql service

6. We need to set root password instead of temporary.
   Using temp password enter to mysql terminal:

> mysql -u root -p<temp_password>

And run command to alter user password:

> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';

AS result I have distinct server using port 4306. And we have an access with root and our new password.

Comment: Excellent solution for your requirements.